# Spark Java error in standalone application

Tags: java, spark-java

I was able to create an executable using launch4j and it works fine on my machine. When I send it to someone to run on their windows machine they get the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/TemplateEngine
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.TemplateEngine
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes - this explains it.  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.TemplateEngine

Comment: probably he doesn't have the dependencies of the app

Comment: This exe runs fine on my machine on which it was developed. I've added all the dependencies in the class path in launch4j

Comment: On the node it's not running, make sure that classpath was properly set and this jar is available in the classpath

Comment: Yes thank you.. that was the issue. Just fixed it .. Had to set a relative class path for the jars

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/6836941). It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This exception may also occur if your maven dependencies do not have `<scope>` set to compile time (default) and dependency jars are not available at compile time. For instance if maven dependencies have `<scope>provided</scope>` in your `pom.xml` compiler will assume that the JRE/environment will provide these dependency jars but when the sources are compiled and these dependencies are not found, this exception will be thrown.

For example - below may lead to this exception if spark-mllib_2.11 dependency is not found during compile time although they are added and there is no error during editing;

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Solved the same problem in my case with IntelliJ IDEA + SBT.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because my version of java that was as default was 9, and somehow Spark didn't recognize it. So I changed to version 8 and it worked. To change in linux :

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

In your case you may want another version, so choose yours (to list the versions you have in your computer use the -l option).

Answer (score 0):

Had to set relative paths in the class path so the executable could locate the jar files

Comment: You could also build a fat jar using maven-assembly-plugin.